# Jquery is not working without settimeout in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, settimeout, meteor-blaze

I have a code in helper in meteorjs

```
Template.tickets.helpers({
    priorityClassColour(priority) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                $(".Low").css('background-color', 'red');
                return 'Low'
            });
    }
})
```

This works fine without any error but when I move the code of jquery css outside settimeout, the style is not applied to css. When I run `$(".Low").css('background-color', 'red');` in browser console then also this works perfectly fine. can somebody tell me why this happens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".Low")` might not exist at the time your jQuery code executes. When you `setTimeout` it allows `$(".Low")` to be available then your jquery works.

You can check `$(".Low").length` outside & inside the `setTimeout` to findout if it exists in both cases or not.

Comment: What if I dont want to use settimeout ?

Comment: Then make sure your Js code detects `$(".Low")`, it will be better to put your js code in the footer. also, run the code when jquery is ready.

Comment: how to do that with meteor helpers

Comment: If you have control over your HTML files then put all the js in footer, only keep jquery in head tag.

Comment: This may be the accepted answer, but mixing JQuery and Blaze is a bad idea unless you need to. You're essentially mixing two different DOM manipulation frameworks that have totally different philosophies. One is imperative and the other is declarative. From a simplicity point of view, best to use just Blaze to get the job done.

Comment: @JordanBaker I am using meteorjs framework.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because you're trying to update something that hasn't rendered yet. That's why using a timeout makes it work, it gives Blaze a chance to finish rendering.

A better way to do it is to set the CSS style of the element using Blaze helper.

In your template use something like:

```
<element style={{priorityClassStyle}}/>
```

Where the `priortyClassStyle` helper would return the whole style string eg. `background-color:red`